# How to run a external JavaScript file on wp-admin if admin, and other if normal user?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm new to WordPress plugins, and I'm trying to load a external JS/jQuery file with some scripts I need. It needs to run in the wp-admin page (not just once when activated). There is a JS file for a common user and another one for the admin.

```
function wp_ui_activation() {
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wp_ui_activation');

function wp_ui_deactivation() {
}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'wp_ui_deactivation');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_ui_scripts');

function wp_ui_scripts() {  
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); //add jquery

    if (!is_admin()) { // it's not admin
        wp_register_script('custom_script', plugins_url('assets/js/custom_script.js', __FILE__),array('jquery')); //register custom_script
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_script'); //add custom_script
    }

    if(is_admin()){ // it's admin
        wp_register_script('custom_admin_script', plugins_url('assets/js/custom_admin_script.js', __FILE__),array('jquery')); //registra custom_admin_script
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_admin_script'); //add custom_admin_script
    }       
}
```

All that resides inside the JS file is a `jQuery(function() {alert("admin")});` and a `jQuery(function() {alert("no-admin")});` but none of them shows up...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register/enqueue your admin scripts on [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts), not on `wp_enqueue_scripts`. `wp_enqueue_scripts` is a front end hook. It won't run on the admin pages.

Secondly, [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) just checks whether the page is an admin page, not whether the user is an administrator. To check whether the user is an administrator use:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if (user_can( $current_user, 'administrator' )) {
  // user is an admin
}
```

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think that @ghaschel want to use `is_admin()` to check if the logged user is an administrator...

Comment: @G-M : That may be true but the question also states "It need it needs to run in the wp-admin page..."

Comment: I writed "the answer is incomplete" and in meantime you updated it... +1 is mandatory ;)

Comment: the script just need to run in the wp-admin page. @G.M. exactly, it should check if the logged user is an admin

Comment: @ghaschel so now you have your solution in this answer: replace `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` with `'admin_enqueue_scripts'` and inside `wp_ui_scripts()` function replace your `if` statement withe the one posted here by s_ha_dum.